# Creating Pie chart / progressbar like arc in andorid

Tags: android, progress-bar, pie-chart, android-progressbar

I am working on a project where I want to show a pie chart like the image added. Already have searched google and other posts in stackoverflow, but could not find a solution. any solution is appreciated.

Note: suggestions of third-party library are also welcome. Also please do not suggest MPAndroidChart as I think my query can be implemented using simpler method.

[image: the pie chart I want to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart to achieve this.

Add below in xml:

```
 <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In java code:

```
PieChart chart = (Piechart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

Example code:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java

There are lot of variances available.

Another library to consider is:

https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

[image]

Comment: have seen it already, I think it is too much for my job @Psypher

Comment: I have included another library which is simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this library - 
https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

I found it be much simpler to use and easier to customise in comparison to the more complex chart libraries like MPChart.

[image: Circlar progress library image sample]